# How can I restore /mnt directory?

Tags: directory, restore

I was making mnt directory in home-directory and when I try delete it, I didn't realize my relative path was root(/).
Eventually I deleted mnt directory in root...
How can I restore /mnt? My file system is ext4.

Comment: I made mnt directory! I'm really really thank your response for letting me know!!

Comment: Consider picking the answer that best helped you.  Click the gray checkmark to accept it.  This is a way of giving back to Askubuntu by making it easy for others to see answers that work.  Also, users who are trying to make sure that all questions have a solution can skip the ones that are resolved.  By the way, **you can avoid this type of problem in the future** by only using the `sudo` command when it's your intentions to do something for the entire system, and not your personal space.  Using `sudo` in your personal space can break the normal access.  **Welcome to AU!**

Answer (score 5):

As long as nothing was mounted to it, `/mnt` is just a directory like any other.

Run `sudo mkdir -m 755 /mnt` to recreate it with default permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Simply by doing `sudo mkdir /mnt`.
`/mnt` normally is an empty directory used to mount something there.

```
$ ls -l /mnt
total 0
$ ls -ld /mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Okt 18  2017 /mnt
```